# Mono Debug - How to turn off?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I turned on the Mono Debug info with:

```
export MONO_OPTIONS=--trace=E:all
export MONO_LOG_MASK=asm
export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

in the Mac's terminal. How do I disable debugging now and return to the normal settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unset all those variables:

```
unset MONO_OPTIONS MONO_LOG_MASK MONO_LOG_LEVEL
```